# Javascript with namespace in R Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, javascript-namespaces

Does any one know how to put Javascript with namespace in R Shiny?
I create a Shiny module to add draggable text to Sankey plot, right click at the text will give an option to remove it from the plot. Everything works well except the add text button. I guess it's due to the namespace issue. Can anyone find a solution for this?

I tried different ways without being able to resolve it

```
mod_graph_sankey_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tabItem(
    id,
    
    shinydashboardPlus::box(
        width = 12,
        title = "File Upload (Node ID variable must be successive integers start from 0)",
        collapsible = TRUE,
        dropdownMenu = reset_dropdown(ns("reset_file")),
        fluidRow(
          column(6, fileInput(ns("sankey"), "Choose an input file", 
                              accept = file_accept))
        ),
        fluidRow(
          column(2, selectInput(ns("sankey_node"),   "Node",    NULL)),
          column(2, selectInput(ns("sankey_node_id"), "Node ID", NULL)),
          column(2, selectInput(ns("sankey_source"), "Source",  NULL)),
          column(2, selectInput(ns("sankey_target"), "Target",  NULL)),
          column(2, selectInput(ns("sankey_value"),  "Value",   NULL))
        )
        
    ),
    shinydashboardPlus::box(width = 12,
        title = "Plot Parameter",
        collapsible = TRUE,
        fluidRow(
          column(3, numericInput(ns('height'), "Plot Height", 400, min=400, max=8000, step=100)),
          column(3, numericInput(ns('width'), "Plot Width", 900, min=400, max=2000, step=100)),
          column(3, numericInput(ns('node_weight'), "Node Weight", 10, min=1, max=20, step=1)),
          column(3, numericInput(ns('pad'), "Node Pad", 15, min=5, max=30, step=1)),
          column(3, numericInput(ns('transparency'), "Transparency", 0.6, min=0.1, max=1, step=0.1)),
          column(9, textInput(ns('title'), "Title", NULL))
        )
    ),
    shinydashboardPlus::box(width = 12,
                            collapsible = TRUE,
                            title = 'Customize the Colors for Sources',
                            fluidRow(
                              column(12, uiOutput(ns("color_input")))
                            )
    ),
    
    
    tags$head(
      tags$script(HTML('
      Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("#{ns("addDraggableText")}", function(message) {
      console.log("Updating text:", newText.id);
Plotly.update(newText.id, { textfont: { size: newSize } });
        var text = message.text;
        var x = message.x;
        var y = message.y;
        var id = message.id;
        
        var newText = document.createElement("div");
        newText.style.position = "absolute";
        newText.style.left = x + "px";
        newText.style.top = y + "px";
        newText.style.cursor = "move";
        newText.innerText = text;
        newText.id = id;
        
        newText.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
          var posX = e.clientX;
          var posY = e.clientY;
          document.onmousemove = function(e) {
            var dx = e.clientX - posX;
            var dy = e.clientY - posY;
            posX = e.clientX;
            posY = e.clientY;
            newText.style.left = (newText.offsetLeft + dx) + "px";
            newText.style.top = (newText.offsetTop + dy) + "px";
          }
          document.onmouseup = function() {
            document.onmousemove = document.onmouseup = null;
          }
        });

        // Add context menu
        newText.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var menu = document.createElement("div");
          menu.id = "contextMenu";
          menu.style.position = "absolute";
          menu.style.left = e.clientX + "px";
          menu.style.top = e.clientY + "px";
          
          var fontSizeOption = document.createElement("div");
          fontSizeOption.innerText = "Change Font Size";
          fontSizeOption.addEventListener("click", function() {
            var newSize = prompt("Enter new font size:");
            if (newSize !== null) {
              Plotly.update(newText.id, {textfont: {size: newSize}});
            }
            menu.remove();
          });

          var removeOption = document.createElement("div");
          removeOption.innerText = "Remove Text";
          removeOption.addEventListener("click", function() {
            newText.remove();
            menu.remove();
          });

          menu.appendChild(fontSizeOption);
          menu.appendChild(removeOption);
          document.body.appendChild(menu);
        });

        document.getElementById("#{ns("sankey_plot")}").appendChild(newText);
      });

    '))
    ),
    
    titlePanel("Draggable Text on Graph"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        textInput(ns("text"), "Enter Text"),
        actionButton(ns("addText"), "Add Text to Graph"),
        textOutput(ns("removeInstruction")),
      ),
    
      shinydashboardPlus::box(width = 12,
                              title = "Sankey Plot",
                              plotlyOutput(ns("sankey_plot"))
      )
    )
  )
}



mod_graph_sankey_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns
      
      rv <- reactiveValues(
        df_sankey = NULL,
      )
      

      #Function to create Tepee plot
      sankey <- function(indata)
      {
        #var1 <- input$sankey_node
        #print(var1)

        #input_data <- indata
        input_data <- indata %>%
          mutate(node := !!sym(input$sankey_node)) %>%
          mutate(node_id := !!sym(input$sankey_node_id)) %>%
          mutate(source := !!sym(input$sankey_source)) %>%
          mutate(target := !!sym(input$sankey_target)) %>%
          mutate(value := !!sym(input$sankey_value))          

        input_data <- select(input_data, node, node_id, source, target, value)

        
        #######################################################################################
        ##################################### Create plot #####################################
        #######################################################################################

        # input_data$source contains integers which represent node, need to get node names to be displayed in
        # color selection section, so user knows which node he/she is choosing color for
        node_name <- input_data %>%
                     select(node_id, node) %>%
                     subset(node!='' & !is.na(node)) %>%
                     arrange(node_id)

        # This data frame contains all node which may not be source
        source_name <- rename(node_name, source=node_id)

        # After merge, this data frame contains only the node which can be source
        source_name <- merge(source_name, select(input_data, source), by='source')

        
        source_name_dedup <- source_name %>% 
          distinct(source, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
          arrange(source)

        # Node can relate to different Node ID, this happens when a therapy (represented by node) can be displayed at
        # the 1st LOT, 2nd LOT, etc. In this case, links flow from them will use the same color. 
        funs <- unique(source_name$node)
        

        
        default_color <- colors()
        cols <- reactive({
          lapply(seq_len(length(funs)), function(i) {
            column(3, colourInput(ns(paste("col", i, sep="_")), funs[i], default_color[i])   )     
          })
        })
        
        output$color_input <- renderUI({cols()})  
        
        # Put all the input in a vector
        colors2 <- reactive({
          lapply(seq_len(length(funs)), function(i) {
            input[[paste("col", i, sep="_")]]
          })
        })
        
        updated_color <- unlist(colors2())
        req(updated_color)
        
        default_color <- updated_color
        if (length(default_color) != length(funs)) {default_color<-colors()}
        
        
        updated_color2 <- paste(sapply(updated_color, function(x) 
                                       {paste0("rgba(", paste(c(col2rgb(x), input$transparency), collapse = "," ), ")") }
                                ), collapse = ", ")
        
        updated_color3 <- vector(length = length(funs))
        test <- strsplit(updated_color2, split=', ')
        for (i in 1:length(funs)) {
          updated_color3[i] <- test[[1]][i]
        }

        color_data <- data.frame(node=unique(source_name$node),
                                 link_color=updated_color3)
        # Due to the fact that node can relate to different Node ID, in the above data frame, we use
        # node=unique(source_name$node) instead of source=unique(source_name$source)
        # Now, need to merge back to get source (which are integers)
        color_data <- merge(color_data, source_name_dedup, by='node')

        input_data <- merge(input_data, select(color_data, -c('node')), by='source', all.x=T)

        
        # Create plot
        p <- plot_ly(
          type = "sankey",
          domain = c(
            x =  c(0,1),
            y =  c(0,1)
          ),
          orientation = "h",
          valueformat = ".0f",
          valuesuffix = " ",
          
          node = list(
            label = node_name$node,
            color = 'black',
            pad = input$pad,
            thickness = input$node_weight,
            line = list(
              color = "black",
              width = 0.5
            )
          ),
          
          link = list(
            source = input_data$source,
            target = input_data$target,
            value =  input_data$value,
            color =  input_data$link_color
          )
        ) %>% 
          layout(
            title = input$title,
            height = input$height,
            width = input$width,
            font = list(
              size = 12
            ),
            xaxis = list(showgrid = F, zeroline = F, showticklabels = F),
            yaxis = list(showgrid = F, zeroline = F, showticklabels = F)
          )
        
        # ggplotly(p, height=input$height)
          p
      }
      #End of the plot function
      
      
      observe({
        req(input$sankey)
        rv$df_sankey <- upload_file(input$sankey)
      })
      
      # Reset fileInputs
      observeEvent(input$reset_file, {
        rv$df_sankey <- NULL
        reset("sankey")
      })
      
      main1 <- reactive({
        req(rv$df_sankey)
        process_file(rv$df_sankey)
      })
      
      observeEvent(input$sankey, {
        var_name <- names(rv$df_sankey)
        default_node      <- grep("^la", var_name, TRUE, value = TRUE)
        default_node_id   <- grep("^lid", var_name, TRUE, value = TRUE)
        default_source    <- grep("^s", var_name, TRUE, value = TRUE)
        default_target    <- grep("^t", var_name, TRUE, value = TRUE)
        default_value     <- grep("^v", var_name, TRUE, value = TRUE)
        
        updateSelectInput(session, "sankey_node",    choices = var_name, selected=default_node)
        updateSelectInput(session, "sankey_node_id", choices = var_name, selected=default_node_id)
        updateSelectInput(session, "sankey_source",  choices = var_name, selected=default_source)
        updateSelectInput(session, "sankey_target",  choices = var_name, selected=default_target)
        updateSelectInput(session, "sankey_value",   choices = var_name, selected=default_value)
      })
        
      output$removeInstruction <- renderText({
        "Right-click on the text to access the context menu for additional options."
      })
      
      ##############################################################################################################
      ###Generate Plot Parameter Input Box (X-axis range, step by value) depend on which efficacy data you upload###
      ##############################################################################################################
      observe({
        output$sankey_plot <- renderPlotly({
          sankey_data <- main1()
          req(sankey_data)
          sankey(indata=sankey_data)
        })
      })
      
      observeEvent(input$addText, {
        text <- input$text
        x <- 0
        y <- 0
        id <- paste0("text_", format(Sys.time(), "%H%M%S"))
        
        print(text)
        print(x)
        print(y)
        print(id)
        
        if (nchar(text) > 0) {
          session$sendCustomMessage("addDraggableText", list(text = text, x = x, y = y, id = id))
        }
      })
    })
}
```

A simplified version without using namespace works well:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(HTML('
      Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("addDraggableText", function(message) {
        var text = message.text;
        var x = message.x;
        var y = message.y;
        var id = message.id;
        
        var newText = document.createElement("div");
        newText.style.position = "absolute";
        newText.style.left = x + "px";
        newText.style.top = y + "px";
        newText.style.cursor = "move";
        newText.innerText = text;
        newText.id = id;
        
        newText.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
          var posX = e.clientX;
          var posY = e.clientY;
          document.onmousemove = function(e) {
            var dx = e.clientX - posX;
            var dy = e.clientY - posY;
            posX = e.clientX;
            posY = e.clientY;
            newText.style.left = (newText.offsetLeft + dx) + "px";
            newText.style.top = (newText.offsetTop + dy) + "px";
          }
          document.onmouseup = function() {
            document.onmousemove = document.onmouseup = null;
          }
        });

        // Add context menu
        newText.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var menu = document.createElement("div");
          menu.id = "contextMenu";
          menu.style.position = "absolute";
          menu.style.left = e.clientX + "px";
          menu.style.top = e.clientY + "px";
          
          var fontSizeOption = document.createElement("div");
          fontSizeOption.innerText = "Change Font Size";
          fontSizeOption.addEventListener("click", function() {
            var newSize = prompt("Enter new font size:");
            if (newSize !== null) {
              Plotly.update(newText.id, {textfont: {size: newSize}});
            }
            menu.remove();
          });

          var removeOption = document.createElement("div");
          removeOption.innerText = "Remove Text";
          removeOption.addEventListener("click", function() {
            newText.remove();
            menu.remove();
          });

          menu.appendChild(fontSizeOption);
          menu.appendChild(removeOption);
          document.body.appendChild(menu);
        });

        document.getElementById("plot").appendChild(newText);
      });

    '))
  ),
  titlePanel("Draggable Text on Sankey Diagram"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("text", "Enter Text"),
      actionButton("addText", "Add Text to Sankey"),
      textOutput("removeInstruction")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$removeInstruction <- renderText({
    "Right-click on the text to access the context menu for additional options."
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    # Sample Sankey diagram
    fig <- plot_ly(
      type = "sankey",
      domain = c(
        x =  c(0,1),
        y =  c(0,1)
      ),
      orientation = "h",
      node = list(
        label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
      ),
      link = list(
        source = c(0, 1, 0, 2, 3),
        target = c(2, 3, 4, 4, 4),
        value = c(8, 4, 2, 8, 4)
      )
    )
    
    fig
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$addText, {
    text <- input$text
    x <- 100  # X-coordinate for initial position
    y <- 100  # Y-coordinate for initial position
    id <- paste0("text_", format(Sys.time(), "%H%M%S"))
    
    print(text)
    print(x)
    print(y)
    print(id)
    
    
    if (nchar(text) > 0) {
      session$sendCustomMessage("addDraggableText", list(text = text, x = x, y = y, id = id))
    }
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tswi.png)

Comment: `ns` is a Shiny function. JavaScript doesn’t know about it. So you need to use `paste` to allow R to construct the character string tha5 defines your JavaScript function before passing it to `addCustomMessageHandler`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried use paste0, but it does not work. I added: print(text), print(x), print(y), print(id) to debug and I found that text, x, y, id are generated by js. Just that they are not added to the plot.

Comment: Try `Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("ID-addDraggableText", ...` where `ID` is the id you use for the module.

Comment: Dear All: I have figured it out!
First use namespace here:
session$sendCustomMessage("addDraggableText", list(text = session$ns(text), x = 10, y = 10, id = session$ns(id_)))

Then add the id name of the module within the js code:
getElementById("g_sankey-sankey_plot")